# Why does not jms serializer show entities in deeper levels?

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have entity `Company` with many `Users` and `User` has many `Tokens`. I would like to serialize Token with User inside.

```
// @JMS\MaxDepth(depth=0)
Token::$user;
```

If I do this, the serialized result will be: `{"token":{"id":2,"user":{},"token":"sxcdftrbgyijmko"}}` notice User is present. If I change MaxDepth to one, the company is missing in output. `{"token":{"id":2,"user":{"id":2,"tokens":[],"name":"Martin"},"token":"sxcdftrbgyijmko"}}`. If I change MaxDepth to two, the company will be serialized as well. Why is company missing for depth one? I tried to achieve this behavior with groups but with same result.

---

I am using [sideloading visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22622830/3397420) and it is critical for me to keep there these empty fields so that visitor will turn them into ids. I also made minimal functional example on [github](https://github.com/Keeo/sideloading-serializer).

Comment: The answer lies in the sideloading custom visitor. If you remove that the depth annotations work as expected.

Comment: Are you sure? I rechecked it and my examples provided here are from that project with commented out visitor.